# Trusting the Return Value Optimization

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, return-value-optimization

How do you go about using the *return value optimization*? 
Is there any cases where I can trust a modern compiler to use the optimization, or should I always go the safe way and return a pointer of some type/use a reference as parameter?

Is there any known cases where the return value optimization cant be made?,
Seems to me that the return value optimization would be fairly easy for a compiler to perform.

Comment: Keep in mind that the compiler may decide to _not_ do this, when it determines the RVO is not actually an optimization in the particular case. Hence, you not only have to trust the compiler to do it when it's useful, but you also have to trust it to _not_ do it when inappropriate.

Comment: To clarify: a common case in which it's inappropriate is when the type returned can be passed in a register, e.g. a `Radians` class. The RVO technique uses space allocated on the stack, and thus has the overhead of accessing memory.

Comment: @MSalters Ok, interesting to know. Basically, the optimization I am interested in is avoiding for example a std::vector<> to be copied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever compiler optimizations are enabled (and in most compilers, even when optimizations are *disabled*), RVO will take place. NRVO is slightly less common, but most compilers will perform this optimization as well, at least when optimizations are enabled.

You're right, the optimization *is* fairly easy for a compiler to perform, which is why compilers almost always do it. The only cases where it "can't be made" are the ones where the optimization doesn't apply: RVO only applies when you return an unnamed temporary. If you want to return a named local variable, NRVO applies instead, and while it is slightly more complex for a compiler to implement, it's doable, and modern compilers have no problem with it.

Comment: Especially, if you have 2 named variables and pick up the one to return at runtime, obviously the compiler cannot perform NRVO :)

Comment: Matthieu, I assume the same goes for two unnamed exits? (ie, "if (...) return A() else return B();"

Comment: @Viktor: No - that's RVO, not **N**RVO. Only one of them will be constructed. So both code paths can use the same memory, which is the memory reserved for the return value. That's the essence of RVO: directly create the return value in the memory reserved for it.

Comment: Matthieu: no, NRVO may still be possible if there are two variables that may be returned. Sometimes my functions have an "if" statement. In one branch I construct a named value, manipulate it and return it; in the other branch I do the same thing but maybe use a different constructor. There's no reason the compiler couldn't optimize that, but I'm pretty sure mine can't (Visual C++).

Answer (score 6):

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization#Compiler_support

Answer (score 2):

To have the best chance that it occurs, you can return an object constructed directly in the return statement [can anyone remember the name for this idiom - I've forgotten it]:

```
Foo f() {
    ....
    return Foo( ... );
}
```

But as with all optimisations, the compiler can always choose not to do it. And at the end of the day, if you need to return a value thee is no alternative to trusting the compiler - pointers and references won't cut it.